# Is it possible to filter email html elements using HTML5 and CSS3 from label buttons?

Tags: html, css, html-email, thunderbird

I was testing this code: https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/kQpAf/
in the context of email html filtering.

The idea would be filtering email body elements (preferible tables or rows) clicking in some labels.

Using Mozilla Thunderbird i was able to send me an email with this html code and once received the filtering was working (tested on version 45.8.0)

Would be possible to position the label buttons inside other elements like ul (in an horizontal navigation bar)?.
How to arrange the sibling selectors?.
From label buttons inside a navigation bar, would be possible to filter separated htm elements as tables or rows of data?

This is the code i'm testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Source: https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/kQpAf/</title>
<head>
<style>

.header-box {
    border: 3px solid red; 
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

div[data-filter="red"]{
  background:red;

}

div[data-filter="green"]{
  background:green;
}

div[data-filter="blue"]{
  background:blue;
}

a:focus[data-filter]{
    opacity:.8;
     outline:none;
}

a[data-filter="red"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="red"]){
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
  font-size:0px;
}

a[data-filter="green"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="green"]){
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
  font-size:0px;
}

a[data-filter="blue"]:focus ~ div:not([data-filter="blue"]){
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
  font-size:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>adapted from: https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/kQpAf/</h2>
<div class="header-box">
<p>This fail:</p>
<a href="#" data-filter="all" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">ALL</a> 
<a href="#" data-filter="red" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">RED</a>
<a href="#" data-filter="green" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">GREEN</a>
<a href="#" data-filter="blue" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">BLUE</a>
<br>
</div>
<br><br>
<p>Working Ok:</p>
<br>
<a href="#" data-filter="all" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">ALL</a> 
<a href="#" data-filter="red" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">RED</a>
<a href="#" data-filter="green" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">GREEN</a>
<a href="#" data-filter="blue" tabindex="-1" moz-do-not-send="true">BLUE</a>
<br><br>

<div data-filter="red" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div data-filter="blue" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<div data-filter="red" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="blue" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
<div data-filter="green" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="red" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="red" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="red" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="blue" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="green" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="blue" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="green" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div data-filter="green" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Some references:

https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/kQpAf/

[image: Thunderbird filter email html elements using HTML5 and CSS3]

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Note: Always needed to add this: moz-do-not-send="true" in every href, example:

..href="#openModal" moz-do-not-send="true"..

Notes: tested in several versions of Mozilla Thunderbird and displays ok the modal window from a text link, also ok closing the modal window. But i'm looking for a way to filter more similar to the first reference above.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

4 Methods CSS3 Tabbed Content, Ian Hansson: http://csscience.com/css3-tabs/

CSS3-Only Tabbed Area, Chris Coyier: https://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/

Note: interactive checkbox technique checkbox hack does not work for Thunderbird recent versions (tested fail on 45.8.0, but surprisingly do function ok with an old version 13.0.1). See for example: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/beating-thunderbirds-checkbox-bug-and-targeting-techniques

The following references all are based in checkbox hack and then discarded in my looking for simple as possible solutions.

http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-tabs-for-email/

Note: Fail in recent versions of Thunderbird. For tests remember always adding  moz-do-not-send="true" for example:

..href="#" style="color: #BDD4FC;" moz-do-not-send="true"..

https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/build-an-interactive-carousel-for-email

[image: A small adaptation of the interactive carousel from images to tables]

https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/10/punched-card-coding-the-secret-of-interactive-email/

https://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/fHmiI

Note that in this example the span element is inside a div (separated from the checkbox) that is related to my question.

Aside Note: in my tests with Thunderbird it seem necesary to always add moz-do-not-send="true" in order to insert links to local files in email body for example:

..href="file://///MYLOCALSERVER/myfolder/temp.html" moz-do-not-send="true"..

Comment: I tested this and it only seems to work in a few clients right now, but it's an intriguing idea. I want to look into this further.

Comment: The idea is intriguing but interactivity in emails are still in the stone age and only limited to iOS, Android and some email clients. If this was done for iOS and Android only then you do this by radio buttons that hide or show elements based on the radio buttons state. You will need a massive fallback for unsupported email clients.

Comment: About interactivity, just to share that i'm finding very good results with Thunderbird and iphone users, adapting from images to tables the code proposed by Geoff Phillips April, 2016 in 'Build an Interactive Carousel for Email.' (link available in the references above). My objective is only to send some kind of 'avance report' to a very limited number of users, all of them using thunderbird, but certainly is a plus the phones availability.